# How to create Integration tests with GoogleBigquery as a backend Database?

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, google-bigquery

I'm working on creating Integration tests for GBQ, but integrating with actual instance of DB will be very expensive, as there is no in-memory instance that would replicate the database behaviour. What is the best approach to create Integration tests with Java Spring Boot as backend framework. Greatly appreciate for the responses.

Solution of simulating behaviour of Google BigQuery instance.

Comment: There is a feature request for creating one https://issuetracker.google.com/savedsearches/559654?pli=1 


Now this is just a possibility, but maybe you can use TestContainers, and run this `ghcr.io/goccy/bigquery-emulator:latest image`?  Then you would have the Go BigQuery Emulator running and you can access it from your Tests.   I have not tested this, just a suggestion for you to try.

https://github.com/goccy/bigquery-emulator

As long as its a docker image, it can be run using TestContainers